# Batch: ECHO is on always when trying to output variable content

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, echo

I'm always getting the message "Echo is on" when trying to run the script..

```
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
C:
cd ..
cd ..
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services" | findstr /b "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DummyService" > "C:\servicePaths.txt"
FOR /f "delims=" %%g IN (servicePaths.txt) do (
  set KEY_NAME="%%g"
  set VALUE_NAME=ImagePath
    FOR /F "tokens=1-3" %%A IN ('REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul') DO (
    set ValueValue=%%C
    )
  echo %ValueValue%
  pause
)
```

Could any batch-guru please help me? I know that it has something to do with the cascaded for-loops, but I cannot find the solutions - no clue anymore after 3 hours try&error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem of expanding the `%ValueValue%`, as this happens when the complete parenthesis block is parsed.
Not when it is executed, but at parse time the `ValueValue` variable is empty, so you get only `echo` which will print `echo is on`.

Simply change it to delayed expansion

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
C:
cd ..
cd ..
set VALUE_NAME=ImagePath

reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services" | findstr /b "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DummyService" > "C:\servicePaths.txt"
FOR /f "delims=" %%g IN (servicePaths.txt) do (
  set "KEY_NAME=%%g"
    FOR /F "tokens=1-3" %%A IN ('REG QUERY !KEY_NAME! /v !VALUE_NAME! 2^>nul') DO (
    set ValueValue=%%C
    )
  echo !ValueValue!
  pause
)
```

Comment: You probably want to add `@ECHO OFF` at the top of the script also.